# @yield and @section is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, layout, laravel-blade

```
this is the code in the main.blade.php so i place an @yield('content') inside the div tags of my bootstrap template but it's that getting the display that should be on the home.blade.php

<div class="container">
     @yield('content')
</div>

this is the code on my home.blade.php

@extends('main')

@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <h1>this content should show on my main</h1>
</div>
@endsection

I dont know why its not working it seems like the @yield and @section is not working by the I'm using laravel 5.4 and it's not displaying any error then what could be wrong

I dont know why its not working it seems like the @yield and @section is not working by the I'm using laravel 5.4 and it's not displaying any error then what could be wrong
```

I dont know why its not working it seems like the @yield and @section is not working by the I'm using laravel 5.4 and it's not displaying any error then what could be wrong

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using all these directives in one file. @yield in the layout file and then use @extend in the views that are rendered by a controller route, for example. @section line up with the corresponding areas of the app layout which they fill in.

Comment: that's what i did i place the @yield on my main.blade.php and on my home.blade.php were my i place the @section('content')